# Kivy ListAdapter/Listview scroll_to from code does not work after touching (example included)

Tags: python, listview, kivy

I'm trying to code a player which shuffles songs, jumps to the shuffled song in a directory `ListView` and scrolls the `ListView` to the song when it is out of view. Sadly this does not work every time.

In the below example the `ListView` will scroll to the required item when you press the button until you touch the `ListView`. After touching/scrolling the `ListView` it will not scroll_to the item anymore.

Any idea on what's wrong with my code?

```
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.adapters.dictadapter import ListAdapter
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.listview import ListView, ListItemButton
from kivy.uix.label import Label

from random import randint

class MainView(BoxLayout):
    items = 400

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainView, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.orientation = 'vertical'
        self.change_from_code = False
        self.list_adapter = ListAdapter(data=["Item #{0}".format(i) for i in range(self.items)], cls=ListItemButton, sorted_keys=[])
        self.list_adapter.bind(on_selection_change=self.selection_change)
        self.list_view = ListView(adapter=self.list_adapter)
        self.add_widget(self.list_view)
        self.status = Label(size_hint_y=.1)
        self.add_widget(self.status)
        self.add_widget(Button(text="select random item", on_press=self.button_pressed,size_hint_y=.1))

    def button_pressed(self, btn):
        index = randint(0, self.items-1)

        self.change_from_code = True
        if not self.list_adapter.get_view(index).is_selected:           # select another random item
            self.list_adapter.get_view(index).trigger_action(duration=0)

    def selection_change(self, adapter, *args):
        selected_index= adapter.selection[0].index      # <--- problem: scroll_to does not work always
        self.list_view.scroll_to(selected_index)

        if self.change_from_code:
            self.status.text= "selection change from code btn %s" %adapter.selection[0].text
        else:
            self.status.text= "selection changed by click btn %s" %adapter.selection[0].text
        self.change_from_code=False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from kivy.base import runTouchApp
    runTouchApp(MainView(width=800))
```

Comment: I can't even run your code on Python 3.4, Kivy v1.9.2-dev0

Comment: runs fine on  [Kivy        ] v1.9.1   [Python      ] v2.7.11 (v2.7.11:6d1b6a68f775, Dec  5 2015, 20:32:19) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)].